# Point data grouping based on location + huge dataset in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select-by-location, point-cloud, big-data

I need community help to solve my puzzle.
I have one huge dataset of points that represent places where a set of trucks stopped. Points go to the database if the reported speed of a truck was 0. The controlling system sends signal every couple minutes. It is ok for the driver to stop where others stop, but if there were just a couple of trucks stopped at a completely new place it is suspicious.

How would you select groups of points, which are not in the specific distance from any other group of points?  Result is selection of all points that have up to 10 (for example) neighbours but all these neighbours as a whole group have no other neighbours in criteria range.

[image: #1]
[image: #2]

Comment: One question per Question, please. It's in the [Tour].

Comment: Convert your points to raster with large cell and sum values then you will see most frequent and less frequent stopped places. I have never tried this with large data. I hope it helps!